# Anybody have anyluck F# Silverlight vs2010?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-3.0, f#, silverlight-4.0

Has anybody had any luck with the following combination

> ```
> F# 2.0
> Silverlight v3
> .NET Framework 4.0
> VS 2010
> ```

I have been trying all night and I just can't seem to adopt any of the existing smaples out there to run...

My goal is to have a silverlight application 100% backed by F#; the examples that are referenced as working are mostly C# silverlight apps calling F# Libraries.  Which in practice should be fine - but I am really trying to impress my girlfriend :)

VS Info (in case it matters):

> ```
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.30128.1 RC1Rel Microsoft
> ```
>
> .NET Framework Version 4.0.30128
>   RC1Rel
>
> ```
> Installed Version: Professional
>
> Microsoft Visual F# 2010
> 01018-315-4422943-70575 Microsoft Visual F# 2010
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This game](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!1910.entry) is entirely F# + SIlverlight (no C#), has Xaml, etc.

Comment: awsome work brian.  it would be gfreat to know your thought process as you started to get this up and running...  What type of project did you start with?  How did you have to modify the project files?  It be cool to have a step by step to a hello world.

Comment: I made a C# console app and a C# silverlight app.  Then I 'diff'ed the two .csproj files.  I made the same changes to the .fsproj file you get for an F# console app.

Comment: We have not published any silverlight app templates because of the F5 bug mentioned in the blog (which is a deep bug/unimplemented feature in the project system), the lack of a Xaml item template, minor bugs (that force you to click 'reload' to get Xaml working inside F# project), etc.  The smooth end-to-end scenario is not there, but you can e.g. just clone my project and then rewrite all the guts as one way to get started.

Comment: Feel free to give me an upvote, in addition to the check mark, if you like the game.  :)  :)  :)

Comment: y - I am stripping your app away to nothing right now.  And then I wanna build up a sample app of my own off "the cloned" base.  that was a smooth idea on the diff of the C# console to C# silverlight project files.  I was trying to pick apart the project files by eye and they really have too much in there to be able to get anything out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/lukeh/archive/2009/06/26/f-in-silverlight.aspx) by Luke Hoban? Looks like the templates he created are a little out of date but it might be possible to hack them to work with VS 2010 RTM.